# manipulating date variables in php

Tags: php, date, variables

Hi I am trying to manipulate date input from the user. 
I am accessing an api that requires a start date and end date, Currently I have the user entering the start date and the end date but I would ideally like the user to be able to input just the start date and the end date automatically assigned 7days later,  I am currently using this code to assign the start and end date, Is it possible to just add 7days to the start date and assign that as the end date?

```
<div class="search-form">
<form action= "" method = "GET">
<div class="form-field">
<input type="type" name="start"  placeholder= "yyyy-mm-dd" value="<?php $startDate; ?>"/>


  </div>
  </form>
   <form action= "" method ="GET">
  <div class="form-field"> 
  <input type ="type" name= "end" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" value ="<?php $endDate;?>"/>

   </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>


  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: please show proper code

Comment: This is the rest $startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(isset($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start'] : date('Y-m-d')));
       $endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(isset($_GET['end']) ? $_GET['end'] : date('Y-m-d')));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this, e.g

```
$date = "Mar 03, 2011";
$date = strtotime($date);
$date = strtotime("+7 day", $date);
echo date('M d, Y', $date);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Cheers  this has helped a lot got it fixed now

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = "2016-08-24"
$startdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+7 days',strtotime($date)));
```

You will get date after 7 days in YYYY-MM-DD format.